# Slick Carousel - Disable controls and interactions by external order

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I'm learning JavaScript and I've got a simple problem that I don't know how to deal with it.

What I want to achieve is to 'hold' or 'freeze' a slide disabling all kind of possible navigation (keyboard arrows, click and drag, touch interaction) by only clicking a `button` when the user desires. By clicking this `button` the user enables or disables the navigation controls with the slider.

So, once clicked this `button` the user can't navigate on the slides. The user has to click again on the `button` to enable the controls.

This is what I got so far:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.slider').slick({
    infinite: true,
    fade: false,
    centerMode: true,
    variableWidth: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    autoplay: false
  });
});

  var hold = false;

  $('#hold').click(function() {
      $(this).attr("class", "active disabled");

      if (hold == false) {
          $('.slider').slick({
            accesibility: false,
            draggable: false,
            swipe: false,
            touchMove: false
          });
          hold = true;

      } else {
        $('.slider').slick({
            accesibility: true,
            draggable: true,
            swipe: true,
            touchMove: true
          });
        hold = false;
        $("#hold").attr("class", "disabled");
      }

  });
```

```css
.card {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 50px 100px;
  background-color: silver;
  color: white;
}

.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.7/slick.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.css" />

<div class="slider">
  <h1 class="card">1</h1>
  <h1 class="card">2</h1>
  <h1 class="card">3</h1>
  <h1 class="card">4</h1>
  <h1 class="card">5</h1>
</div>

<button id="hold" class="disabled">HOLD</button>
```

What could I've been missing?

Your help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `slickSetOption` to `set an individual value live`.  See the `Methods` section at http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Below is a working example.

```js
var slider = $("#slider");
slider.slick({
  arrows: false,
  centerMode: true,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  variableWidth: true
});

var hold = false;
$("#hold").click(function() {
  slider.slick("slickSetOption", "accessibility", hold);
  slider.slick("slickSetOption", "draggable", hold);
  slider.slick("slickSetOption", "swipe", hold);
  slider.slick("slickSetOption", "touchMove", hold);
  
  hold = !hold;
  
  $(this).toggleClass("disabled");
});
```

```css
h1 {
  background-color: silver;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 50px 100px;
}

.disabled {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <h1>1</h1>
  <h1>2</h1>
  <h1>3</h1>
  <h1>4</h1>
  <h1>5</h1>
</div>
<button id="hold">HOLD</button>
```

Comment: The accesibility option still runs, what could it be? Anything else works well, thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Ermac I fixed the example.  There was a spelling mistake... oops.