# Slick.js: Prevent sliding to a slide under a specific condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I'm using [Slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) for my carousel and I would like to prevent sliding to a slide when a specific condition is met. I'm trying to acheive this by unsing the `beforeChange` event:

```
$('.my-slider').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {

  if (nextSlide > 3) {
     return false;
  }

});
```

However, this doesn't prevent the sliding.

**Is there any way in Slick to prevent sliding?**

Generic situation: The "Next" button (or a "dot") is clicked, but the slide should not be shown yet. No way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately slick can't handle this situation for now. There are some PRs with this functionality waiting. See this discussion: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/pull/2104

Answer (score 0):

you can put a another overlay button with position absolute, exactly above this button. Then immediately before reach this slide, hide this slick button, and unhide your overlay button.

Then do something like this

> .hide { display:none; }
>
> ```
> $('.slider').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
>
>     if(nextSlide==4){
>         $('.slick-next.slick-arrow').addClass('hide');        
>         $('.aboveSlickNext:eq(7)').removeClass('hide');
>     }
>     else{
>         $('.slick-next.slick-arrow').removeClass('hide');       
>         $('.aboveSlickNext:eq(7)').addClass('hide');
>     }
> });
> ```

hope this idea help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and resolved it with this function.

```js
function setSliderFrozen($slider, isFrozen) {
  const allowSlideChange = !isFrozen;

  $slider.slick('slickSetOption', 'accessibility', allowSlideChange);
  $slider.slick('slickSetOption', 'draggable', allowSlideChange);
  $slider.slick('slickSetOption', 'swipe', allowSlideChange);
  $slider.slick('slickSetOption', 'touchMove', allowSlideChange);
}
```

Credits: [Slick Carousel - Disable controls and interactions by external order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40272476/slick-carousel-disable-controls-and-interactions-by-external-order)