# Slickjs prevent going to slide

Tags: javascript, slider, slick.js

I'm trying to prevent the slider from going to a specific slide but with no success.
I have a slider that has slides from 0-5 and what I'm trying to do is to prevent the slider from going to the slide 0 .I don't want to remove the slider 0 just to prevent the slider from going to it.
I've tried to 2 different methods but is still going to the slide 0

```js
 $('.slider-for').slick({
   slidesToShow: 1,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   arrows: true,
   infinite: false,
   initialSlide: 2,
 });

 $("body").on("click", ".slick-prev", function(event) {
   if ($('.slider').slick('slickCurrentSlide') == 1) {
     $('.slider').slick('slickGoTo', 1);
   }
 });


 $('.slider').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  var slide_no = nextSlide + 1;
    if(slide_no == 1) {
     $('.slider').slick('slickGoTo', 1);
    }
 });
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

.main {
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 500px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h3 {
  background: #fff;
  color: #3498db;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 2%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.action {
  display: block;
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.action a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #f30;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.action a:hover {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="slider slider-for">
    <div><h3>0</h3></div>
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slick.js: Prevent sliding to a slide under a specific condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49098030/slick-js-prevent-sliding-to-a-slide-under-a-specific-condition)

Comment: I'm sorry, man. But doesn't look like it by following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49098030/slick-js-prevent-sliding-to-a-slide-under-a-specific-condition)